# Does purchase from Amazon.in void Apple warranty?

Tags: mac, mac-mini, warranty

I want to purchase a [Mac Mini](http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=mac%20mini%20i5) from [amazon.in](http://amazon.in) not [amazon.com](http://amazon.com); local apple store told me that if you purchase apple product from unauthorized reseller they will not provide me any support.

I searched for authorized apple resellers and I found [amazon.com](http://amazon.com) listed there, but did not find [amazon.in](http://amazon.in).

My question is if I purchase Mac Mini from amazon.in will Apple be providing me warranty cover and support for next one year from the date of purchase? Is my local apple store is playing trick so that I buy from there?

Comment: Don't they have it on .com?

Comment: It is but I don't think they will be shipping to India.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon.in, Amazon.com that's the same, so it won't void anything.

Amazon.in is targeted just for indian customers.

Comment: Thanks for your response. According to Apple sources Amazon.com is not theirs authorized reseller for iPad. http://salesresources.apple.com/sp/catalog/
If I buy an iPad from Amazon.com then will apple give me the same warranty cover?

Comment: As you might see, Amazon does not sell iPads directly but only through 3rd parties.

Comment: Ok one more question, what if third parties are not authorized resellers from Apple? I see big difference in price from Apple authorized resellers and online stores like Amazon.

Comment: From what I saw the main problem will be that the waranty starts from when the resellers buyed the iPad and not when the end-buyer buys the iPad.